# Active directory account expire notification power shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Please do not confuse my question with Password Expire notification. Does anyone know powershell script that can be used to notify a User that their Active Directory User Account is about to expire in X amount of days?
Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: You could get the value of the AccountExpires property, convert it, and alert if the converted value meets some criteria of yours (less than 5 days, et. al) This article demonstrates a way to do it:
https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/ad/dealing-accountexpires-date-active-directory-powershell/

Answer (score 4):

The `Search-ADAccount` command that is a part of the ActiveDirectory module is designed to search for this (as well as similar queries) already:

```
$30Days = New-TimeSpan -Days 30
$ExpiringAccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan $30Days -UsersOnly
```

You could then, for example, iterate over these users and combine it with `Send-MailMessage` to send emails.